# Intersection between a curve and a line in the affine plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am struggling with an exercise in Fulton's "Algebraic Curves An Introduction to Algebraic Geometry".

Suppose $C$ is an affine plane curve and $L$ is an affine Line in $A^2(k)$ such that $L$ is not contained in $C$. Let $C=V(F)$, $F \in k[X,Y]$ a polynomial of degree $n$. I want to show that $L \cap C$ is a finite set of no more than n points. There already was an answer to the same question here:

[An affine plane curve and intersection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759086/an-affine-plane-curve-and-intersection)

> A point $(x,y)$ in $L\cap C$ satisfies $y=ax+b$ and $F(x,y)=0$. So every such point is a zero of the polynomial $F(X,aX+b)$. Inductively it is easy to show that $F(X,aX+b)$ defines a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ in $K[X]$. So there are at most $n$ points in $L\cap C$.
>
> EDIT: obviously, I assume $C\neq L$."

What I don't understand about this answer is why $F(X,aX + b)$ is a polynomial in one variable. How can $(x,y)$ be a zero value of such a polynomial?

Comment: What happens when you do an example? Try it with $F(x,y)=y-x^2$ and $L$ given by $y=x+1$.

Comment: I know this is probably not the intended solution, but if (a1,a2) is in L∩C, then $(a_1)^2 = a_1 + 1$ so $(a_1)^2 - a_1 = 0$ so $a_1$ is a zero value of $X^2 - X$, therefore it must be 1 or 0. Now if we plug in these finitely many solutions into one of our originial polynomials, we get a polynomial in one variable, which can only have finitely many solutions?

Comment: You've made an arithmetic mistake, but otherwise your idea is fine. I really would encourage you to try it in the manner indicated if you want to understand that solution: what happens when you substitute in for $y$ in the equation of $F$ according to the information you have from $L$?

Comment: Oh if I substitute for $y$,  I get $F(X,X+1)$.  Then the zero values of this are possible solutions for $a_1$ which are finitely many. With the information from the Equation L I get the set of  the second coordinates and all solutions. Edit: In general the same trick applies for F(x,ax+b). This is just substituting for y. Thanks a lot!